# Fetching next valid day

Tags: java, date

I am writing one java application where i need to do the following.

I have to avoid two days of a week (externally configurable) say TUESDAY and FRIDAY to do some business logic processing. I want to find out the next available day. For Example : if today is TUESDAY, I should get WEDNESDAY as next available or if today is THURSDAY, then the next available should be MONDAY.

Could someone guide me solving this ? This sounds simple but its really trickey.

Here is what i did so far

```
       List<String> exceptionDays = new ArrayList<String>();
  exceptionDays.add("SUNDAY");
  exceptionDays.add("MONDAY");
  exceptionDays.add("FRIDAY");

  Date today = new Date();

      Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
      calendar.setTime(today);

  int dayOfWeek = calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK);

  if (dayOfWeek == Calendar.FRIDAY) {
      calendar.add(Calendar.DATE, 3);
  } else if (dayOfWeek == Calendar.SATURDAY) {
      calendar.add(Calendar.DATE, 2);
  } else {
      calendar.add(Calendar.DATE, 1);
  }
  String strDateFormat = "E";
  SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat(strDateFormat);

  strDateFormat = "EEEE";
  sdf = new SimpleDateFormat(strDateFormat);

  Date nextBusinessDay = calendar.getTime();
  System.out.println(sdf.format(nextBusinessDay).toUpperCase());
  if(exceptionDays.contains(sdf.format(nextBusinessDay).toUpperCase())){
      if(sdf.format(nextBusinessDay).toUpperCase().equals("FRIDAY")){
          calendar.add(Calendar.DATE, 3);
      }else if(sdf.format(nextBusinessDay).toUpperCase().equals("SATURDAY")){
          calendar.add(Calendar.DATE, 2);
      } else
          calendar.add(Calendar.DATE, 1);


   nextBusinessDay = calendar.getTime();
  }
  DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-yy");
    String format = df.format(nextBusinessDay.getTime());
  System.out.println("Today            : " + df.format(today));
  try {
    System.out.println("Next business day: " + df.parse(format));

      System.out.println("Next business day: " + df.format(nextBusinessDay));
```

Please ignore above logic if it looks clumsy.

Answer (score 1):

Simple use `Calendar`

```
List<Integer>  avoidingDays = new ArrayList<Integer>();
avoidingDays.add(Calendar.MONDAY);
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
while(avoidingDays.contains(cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK)) ){cal.add(Calendar.DATE, 1}
return cal;
```

Comment: This code ignores the crucial issue of time zone, implicitly depending on the JVM’s [current default](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/TimeZone.html#setDefault-java.util.TimeZone-) time zone which can be changed at any moment by any code in any thread of this JVM. Better to specify the desired/expected [time zone](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/TimeZone.html).