# How can I build a method to convert today's date into the next working day?

Tags: java

I have a problem in java. I would like to know how to get the date of the next working day. The date format is DD/MM/YYYY. This is difficult as you can't simply add a single number onto the day, what if the next day is the next month or even another year. 
   I also need to make sure the next day is not a weekend day and is the next working day. 
   Another problem is bank holidays but I am not currently thinking about this.

Is there a method that does this job.
   Any help would be great!!

Comment: Did you know that the Calendar class exists?

Comment: I would suggest looking at http://www.joda.org/joda-time/

Comment: add () method of Calendar class

Comment: Thanks Ive had a look at the Calendar class add method but what if the next day is on a weekend?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Fetching next valid day](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10072914/fetching-next-valid-day). You need to know how to parse a string into a date-time object, and then use that object to find the next appropriate day. Both topics have been handled *hundreds* of times on StackOverflow. Please **search before posting**.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example, but it doesn't respect public holidays, which is much more complex to check than just the weekend days:

```
public static void main(String args[]) {
    String yourDate = "21/11/2014";

    try {
        SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
        Date current = format.parse(yourDate);

        Calendar cal = new GregorianCalendar();
        cal.setTime(current);

        do {
            cal.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 1);
        } while (cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK) == Calendar.SATURDAY
                || cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK) == Calendar.SUNDAY);

        Date workday = cal.getTime();
        System.out.println("Next Workday: " + format.format(workday));
    } catch (ParseException ex) {
        System.err.println(ex);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Ad Mikea suggested, [JodaTime](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) is an excellent library for Date(Time) calculations.

Just a small code fragment to get you exited/started:

```
isSaturday = LocalDate.now().plusDays(1).getDayOfWeek() == DateTimeConstants.SATURDAY;
```

Comment: Thanks, the only reason why I didn't use it when suggested was because it was a litle complex but I'm going to look into it. Thanks. You all deserve mark ups but my hands are tied. :)